# How to store multiple value in a field which has relationship with other table

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, relationship

I am working on a 'contact databse' using mysql database and codeigniter. Some of my table structure is as below

```
Organization ->  fld_id
                 fld_orgname
                 fld_orgaddress

Department   ->  fld_id
                 fld_org_id (has relationship with organization)
                 fld_deptname
                 fld_details

Designation  ->  fld_id
                 fld_dept_id (has relationship with organization)
                 fld_desgname

usertable    ->  fld_id
                 fld_desg (has relationship with Designation)
                 fld_dept (has relationship with Department)
                 fld_org (has relationship with organization)
```

Now the problem is, sometime a person may work in multiple organization. Then how could i insert this multiple value sequentially to usertable?

Comment: Does  "usertable" hold other information regarding the "person"? Or is there some other table?

Comment: usertable has many other column like name, age, phone but they has no relationship with others thats why i didn't mention them

Comment: I thought so but wanted to be sure.

Comment: You can perhaps have another table `userOrganization` containing fields like `user_id`, `fld_desg`, `fld_dept`, `fld_org`, etc. And then `usertable` will have `fld_id`, `name`, `age`, etc. This way multiple user-organization entries can go into `userOrganization`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Sorry about my english if im not clear)

If i'm understanding this correctly a user can work in more than one organization and an organization can have multiple users, uno solution may be to create a junction table

```
JUNCTION_ORG_USER -> fld_id_user (usertable) REFERENCES usertable(fld_id)
                  -> fld_id_org (organization) REFERENCES organization(fld_id)
```

Or if u dont want (or can't) to normalize, u can repeat the row changing the organization id

Also as u are using codeigniter, and this applies if u create a junction table,
u can use

```
$this->db->insert_batch('table_name', $array);
```

Just build the array like the [documentation indicated](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html)

```
$data = array(
    array(
            'fld_id' => 'TheUserId',
            'fld_org' => 'OrganizationId_1'
    ),
    array(
            'fld_id' => 'TheUserId',
            'fld_org' => 'OrganizationId_2'
    )
 );

 $this->db->insert_batch('mytable', $data);
```

Hope my answer helps u.

Comment: Thank you very much. This really help me a lot.

Comment: Happy to help :D

Answer (score 2):

One answer is to create another cross reference table for storing the connection between a user and an organization. That way there can easily be a one to many relationship between a person and organizations

```
user_org => fld_id 
            user (usertable.fldid)
            org  (Organization.fld_id)
```

You should then remove fld_org (has relationship with organization) from usertable